# PKCS#11 instantiation problems

Tags: java, cryptography, digital-signature, pkcs#11

I am trying to sign a pdf file using the smart card and PKCS#11. I link the right .dll and I am making a configuration file dynamically, but I am running into configuration trouble.

```
String config = "name=zz\n" +
                "library=" + DLL + "\n" +
                "slotListIndex = " + getSlotsWithTokens(DLL)[0];
ByteArrayInputStream pot = new ByteArrayInputStream(config.getBytes());
Provider providerPKCS11 = new SunPKCS11(pot);
```

and I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.security.ProviderException: Initialization failed
    at sun.security.pkcs11.SunPKCS11.<init>(SunPKCS11.java:376)
    at sun.security.pkcs11.SunPKCS11.<init>(SunPKCS11.java:107)
    at smartCardPKCS11.scPKCS11.main(scPKCS11.java:56)
Caused by: java.security.ProviderException: slotListIndex is 52481 but token only has 10 slots
    at sun.security.pkcs11.SunPKCS11.<init>(SunPKCS11.java:357)
    ... 2 more
```

bit confused on the whole slots thing. Can someone help me out?

This how my getSlotsWithTokens looks:

```
public static long[] getSlotsWithTokens(String libraryPath) throws IOException{
        CK_C_INITIALIZE_ARGS initArgs = new CK_C_INITIALIZE_ARGS();
        String functionList = "C_GetFunctionList";

        initArgs.flags = 0;
        PKCS11 tmpPKCS11 = null;
        long[] slotList = null;
        try {
            try {
                tmpPKCS11 = PKCS11.getInstance(libraryPath, functionList, initArgs, false);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
                throw ex;
            }
        } catch (PKCS11Exception e) {
            try {
                initArgs = null;
                tmpPKCS11 = PKCS11.getInstance(libraryPath, functionList, initArgs, true);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
               ex.printStackTrace();
            } catch (PKCS11Exception ex) {
               ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        try {
            slotList = tmpPKCS11.C_GetSlotList(true);

            for (long slot : slotList){
                CK_TOKEN_INFO tokenInfo = tmpPKCS11.C_GetTokenInfo(slot);
                System.out.println("slot: "+slot+"\nmanufacturerID: "
                        + String.valueOf(tokenInfo.manufacturerID) + "\nmodel: "
                        + String.valueOf(tokenInfo.model));
            }
        } catch (PKCS11Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            t.printStackTrace();
        }

        return slotList;

    }
```

**UPDATED version:**

So I made the changes as @albciff suggested: here is the complete code:

```
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.security.GeneralSecurityException;
import java.security.KeyStore;
import java.security.PrivateKey;
import java.security.Provider;
import java.security.Security;
import java.security.cert.Certificate;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.List;

import org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider;

import sun.security.pkcs11.SunPKCS11;
import sun.security.pkcs11.wrapper.CK_C_INITIALIZE_ARGS;
import sun.security.pkcs11.wrapper.CK_TOKEN_INFO;
import sun.security.pkcs11.wrapper.PKCS11;
import sun.security.pkcs11.wrapper.PKCS11Exception;

import com.itextpdf.text.DocumentException;
import com.itextpdf.text.Rectangle;
import com.itextpdf.text.log.LoggerFactory;
import com.itextpdf.text.log.SysoLogger;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfSignatureAppearance;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfStamper;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.security.BouncyCastleDigest;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.security.CrlClient;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.security.CrlClientOnline;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.security.DigestAlgorithms;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.security.ExternalDigest;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.security.ExternalSignature;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.security.MakeSignature;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.security.PrivateKeySignature;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.security.TSAClient;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.security.MakeSignature.CryptoStandard;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.security.OcspClient;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.security.OcspClientBouncyCastle;

public class sPKCS11  {
    public static final String SRC = "src/Test.pdf";
    public static final String DEST = "src/scTest.pdf";
    public static final String DLL = "c:/windows/system32/aetpkss1.dll";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException, DocumentException {
        LoggerFactory.getInstance().setLogger(new SysoLogger());
        String pkcs11ConfigSettings = "name=aet\n"+"library="+DLL;
        byte[] pkcs11ConfigBytes = pkcs11ConfigSettings.getBytes();
        ByteArrayInputStream confStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(pkcs11ConfigBytes);

        SunPKCS11 pkcs11 = new SunPKCS11(confStream);
        Security.addProvider(pkcs11);

        BouncyCastleProvider providerBC = new BouncyCastleProvider();
        Security.addProvider(providerBC);

        KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS11");
        ks.load(null, null);
        Enumeration<String> aliases = ks.aliases();
        while (aliases.hasMoreElements()) {
            System.out.println(aliases.nextElement());
        }
        // alias is here just for the sake of keeping things private
        smartcardsign(pkcs11.getName(), ks, "alias");
    }

    public static void smartcardsign(String provider, KeyStore ks, String alias) throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException, DocumentException {
        PrivateKey pk = (PrivateKey)ks.getKey(alias, null);
        Certificate[] chain = ks.getCertificateChain(alias);
        OcspClient ocspClient = new OcspClientBouncyCastle();
        List<CrlClient> crlList = new ArrayList<CrlClient>();
        crlList.add(new CrlClientOnline(chain));
        scPKCS11 app = new scPKCS11();
        app.sign(SRC, String.format(DEST, alias), chain, pk, DigestAlgorithms.SHA256, provider, CryptoStandard.CMS,
                "Test", "B", crlList, ocspClient, null, 0);
    }

    public void sign(String src, String dest,
            Certificate[] chain, PrivateKey pk,
            String digestAlgorithm, String provider, CryptoStandard subfilter,
            String reason, String location,
            Collection<CrlClient> crlList,
            OcspClient ocspClient,
            TSAClient tsaClient,
            int estimatedSize)
                    throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException, DocumentException {
        // Creating the reader and the stamper
        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);
        FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(dest);
        PdfStamper stamper = PdfStamper.createSignature(reader, os, '\0', null, true);
        // Creating the appearance
        PdfSignatureAppearance appearance = stamper.getSignatureAppearance();
        appearance.setReason(reason);
        appearance.setLocation(location);
        appearance.setVisibleSignature(new Rectangle(36, 748, 144, 780), 1, "sig");
        appearance.setCertificationLevel(PdfSignatureAppearance.CERTIFIED_NO_CHANGES_ALLOWED);
        // Creating the signature
        ExternalSignature pks = new PrivateKeySignature(pk, digestAlgorithm, provider);
        ExternalDigest digest = new BouncyCastleDigest();
        MakeSignature.signDetached(appearance, digest, pks, chain, crlList, ocspClient, tsaClient, estimatedSize, subfilter);
    }
}
```

And this is the new error msg:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.security.KeyStoreException: PKCS11 not found
    at java.security.KeyStore.getInstance(Unknown Source)
    at smartCardPKCS11.sPKCS11.main(sPKCS11.java:65)
Caused by: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: PKCS11 KeyStore not available
    at sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.Security.getImpl(Unknown Source)
    ... 2 more
```

I am aware that it is something really stupid, help is welcomed.

Comment: What is the value of `getSlotsWithTokens(DLL)[0];`? According to your exception, it's 52481. If that's true, that is a highly unlikely value and you should take a look at your `getSlotsWithTokens()` method. You'll find the error there.

Comment: using a.e.t europe b.v. aetpkss1.dll

Comment: What is sent to the `System.out`? Maybe the `C_GetTokenInfo()` method is wrong. If so, that's a question for AET. In any case: this is really off topic regarding iText. Finding the correct slot in an HSM isn't related to PDF in any way.

Comment: thanks for your time Bruno, has to be something from providers side (AET). Didn't want to waste anybody's time..will remove itext tag

Comment: GetSlotList returns a list of slot ids, and you seem to need to pass the index of the slot in the list, rather than the ID of the token.

Comment: can please help me out, can't seem to find my way around @EugeneMayevski'EldoSCorp

Comment: Well, the question is 8 years old, but in case somebody stumbles upon this, I think the initial problem is that slotListIndex is an index in the list of slots, not a slotId. In order to use one of the slots returned by C_GetSlotList(), you want 'slot=<slot>', as far as I understand from the docs. slotListIndex=0 means use the first slot in the list, exactly what you want, and is the default.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem.

Try passing `-Djava.security.debug=sunpkcs11` to jvm. I did this and it worked.

If you are using `jarsigner` or `keytool` pass `-J-Djava.security.debug=sunpkcs11` instead.

See [OpenJDK bug](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8039912). This issue is solved in OpenJDK, but maybe it is still unresolved in Oracle JDK.

Answer (score 3):

Inform the `slotListIndex` in the config it's optional (however the method `getSlotsWithTokens()` is not   returning the value you expect). You can see the `slotListIndex` parameter description in [`PKCS11 Reference`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/p11guide.html):

> This is the slot index that this provider instance is to be associated with. It is the index into the list of all slots returned by the PKCS#11 function C_GetSlotList. For example, 0 indicates the first slot in the list. At most one of slot or slotListIndex may be specified. **If neither is specified, the default is a slotListIndex of 0.**

So config only `name` and `library` parameter to configure your `PKCS11` provider to avoid your exception:

```
// Configure the Sun PKCS#11 provider. It requires a stream 
// containing the configuration parameters - "name" and "library".
String pkcs11ConfigSettings = "name = " + pkcs11ID + "\n" + "library = " + libraryPath;
byte[] pkcs11ConfigBytes = pkcs11ConfigSettings.getBytes();
ByteArrayInputStream confStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(pkcs11ConfigBytes);

// instantiate the provider
SunPKCS11 pkcs11 = new SunPKCS11(confStream);
Security.addProvider(pkcs11);   
...
```

#### EDIT:

In your code now you're loading the provider correctly so the `java.security.KeyStoreException: PKCS11 not found` is thrown in the follow invocation `KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS11");` because your smartcard is not plugged or if it's plugged maybe there is some problem with the provider (both problems thrown the same exception), so try to pass the provider explicitly to the instance using [`getInstance(String,Provider)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/KeyStore.html#getInstance(java.lang.String,%20java.security.Provider)):

Use:

```
SunPKCS11 pkcs11 = new SunPKCS11(confStream);
KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS11", pkcs11);
```

Instead of:

```
KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS11");
```

Furthermore there is an error in your code: you have to provide the *PKCS11* password not `null` when you try to load the keystore.

So use:

```
ks.load(null, "yourPassword".toCharArray());
```

Instead of:

```
ks.load(null, null);
```

*Note* alternatively its very common to use a [password callback handler to access *PKCS11* keystores](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/p11guide.html#Login).

Putting all together, the code could be:

```
// Configure the Sun PKCS#11 provider. It requires a stream 
// containing the configuration parameters - "name" and "library".
String pkcs11ConfigSettings = "name = " + pkcs11ID + "\n" + "library = " + libraryPath;
byte[] pkcs11ConfigBytes = pkcs11ConfigSettings.getBytes();
ByteArrayInputStream confStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(pkcs11ConfigBytes);

// instantiate the provider
SunPKCS11 pkcs11 = new SunPKCS11(confStream);
Security.addProvider(pkcs11);   
KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS11", pkcs11);
ks.load(null, "yourPassword".toCharArray());
```

Comment: tried it, updated my question with the output i get,thanks but still having some problems @albciff

Comment: @caniaskyouaquestion will update my answer because I see some wrong things in your code... however firstly I've to say that now you're loading the provider correctly and `java.security.KeyStoreException: PKCS11 not found` this time is thrown because your smartcard is not plugged.

Comment: yeah, I am pass the point of loading the provider... but my smartcard is plugged in :( @albciff

Comment: @caniaskyouaquestion if it's plugged maybe the problem is with the provider (the thrown error is the same for both cases). I update my answer I think that this time could work `:)`.

Comment: it still shows error on line: KeyStore instance = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS11",pkcs11); the smartcard is inserted and working, i just can't get it to work through pkcs11..thanks for  trying

Comment: It seems odd to me, this code must works. Who can knows what is happening `:(`. Anyway if it's not a problem I will edit your question in order it be more clear and maybe attract more attention  to have more answers `:)`

Comment: no problems at all, as I have already said, thanks a lot..we are both confused as why this won't work.. maybe somebody will shed some light on this subject :) @albciff

Comment: @caniaskyouaquestion I'm a bit confused, because I know that this code must works, and I'm sure that the last exception is related to what I'm saying... however I'm just curious if there is some other thing happening.

Comment: will let you know if I figure this out somehow @albciff